# Автоматическое обновление сайта с github

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, github, веб-сервер

Пишу личный сайт на python (Django), сайт хостится на sprinthost. И в связи с постоянной сменой рабочего устройства и работы, появилась необходимость автообновления файлов сайта с github. Читал на форумах, что это возможно, но ничего конкретного. Подскажите, как это можно организовать.

Comment: Конкретно — разбирайтесь с Travis CI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заинтересовал ваш вопрос и решил погуглить.

1. Советуют https://developer.github.com/webhooks/
2. Еще предлагают почитать про непрерывную интеграцию. Ссылки там на PHP исходники, но [ссыль оставлю](https://github.com/antriver/auto-git-pull)

> Перейдя на VPS откройте для себя мир CI(непрерывной интеграции), если разобраться с системами CI будет совсем тяжко, то есть простые скрипты

Сам я пользовался [capistrano](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/installation/). Но это не автоматически обновляет продакшен, а полуавтоматически. Чтобы залить, должен быть установлен капистрано и запустить команду `cap production deploy`. Конфиг с установочниками можно залитьна флешку и где надо ставить и потом удалять

Comment: В итоге проблему я решил немного иначе, на хостинге сайта sprinthost можно получить доступ к ssh и ftp. Я настроил через Gitlab CI что бы файлы отправлялись на сайт по ftp. Спасибо за ваш ответ.